# Comments not appending to correct div and div toggle causes jump to page top

Tags: jquery

I've been working on a commenting system over the past few days but have encountered several problems:

1. Message comments are not appended to the correct div - how do I
   go about appending a comment to the correct div and then creating a
   new div that would allow for another comment to be made
2. Whenever the user clicks on the 'Comment' link for an element
   much lower down the page, they get moved up to the top of page which
   causes confusion

How do I resolve these issues?

I have posted up a demo of my system here because there is quite a bit of code to go through: http://jsfiddle.net/BQ84D/3/

Here is the relevant JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comment_button').click(function () {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");
        var comment = $("#ctextarea" + ID).val();
        var dataString = 'comment=' + comment + '&msg_id=' + ID;
        if (comment.match(/^\s*$/)) {
            $(function () {
                $("#dialog-message2").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        } else {
            var stuff = '<div class="stcommentbody" id="stcommentbody"><div class="stcommentimg"><img src="sri.jpg" class="small_face"/></div> <div class="stcommenttext">' + comment + '<div class="stcommenttime"></div> </div></div>';
            $("#commentload" + ID).append(stuff);
            $("#ctextarea" + ID).val('');
            $("#ctextarea" + ID).focus();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Whenever you move up after a click on a button or a link, it is a sign you need to return false or add e.preventDefault() in a click handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/gxELB/

I've added the following code to insert the comment before the comment box

```
$('<div class="commentcontainer" id="commentload5"><div class="stcommentbody" id="stcommentbody5"><div class="stcommentimg"><img src="" class="small_face"></div><div class="stcommenttext">    <b>Test</b>&nbsp;' + comment + '<div class="stcommenttime">8 days ago</div></div></div></div>').insertBefore('#commentbox' + ID);
```

I've also added the following code to prevent form submission so that the demo works.

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

To resolve issue #2, I've removed the href="#" attribute. You may also do an e.preventDefaut() to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ84D/4/)

`Point 1.`

I think you just have one div `commentload` in the fiddle.

`Point 2.`

```
$("[id^='commentlink']").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <--prevent the default behavior clicked link
});
```

If you `.preventDefault()` in all the links clicked or use the above one then page won't jump to the top whenever a link is clicked which id starts with `commentlink`